# trigger jquery file upload from summernote image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to trigger the jquery file upload method after selecting an image from summernote so I can use the URL instead of the base64 encoding.

Here's my current call:

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
        toolbar: [
                  ['edit',['undo','redo']],
                  ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 
                  ['insert', ['link','picture']],
                  ['view', ['fullscreen']]
               ],
    onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
        uploadFile(files, editor, welEditable);
    }
});
```

I'm able to call into my uploadFile function and pass the args but I'm not clear how to pass them along to my jquery file upload call...I know that file_upload is bound to the input button so is there anyway to bypass this and trigger the upload grammatically?

```
function uploadFile(files, editor, welEditable) {

     /* 
     $('#file_upload').fileupload('add', {
        fileInput: files
     });
     */

     $('#file_upload').fileupload({
         url: 'photos/index.php',
         done: function (e, data) {
             $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {

                editor.insertImage(welEditable, url);
            });
        }
    });
}
```